# Tricky polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Is there any way of solving this equation for $x$
$$-1 + x+ ax(a+bx^h)^4 = 0$$
where $h\in\mathbb{N}$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$.

This is the most simplified version of such equation I could write, and I suspect this is not possible to solve in general, but I was wondering if something could be said about $x$. Any ideas?

The motivation behind such equation comes from a [previous question I made](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4279408/simplifying-a-binomial-sum).

Comment: I think the best that can be done is [approach the roots of the polynomial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Newton%27s_Method).

Comment: An equivalent equation for $x\in\Bbb R$ is $x^{h+\frac14}+\frac ab x^\frac14=\pm\frac1{b\sqrt[4]{a+1}}$. You can substitute $x^\frac14=w$ and get a [general](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463894/how-to-solve-xy-ax-b/4464966#4464966) [trinomial](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial) equation which have closed forms using [FoxH](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html) and another Wolfram function.

Answer (score 2):

*This must be tried before concluding.*

Let me suppose that you are looking for the first zero of function
$$f(x)=-1 + x+ a\,x\,(a+b\,x^h)^4 $$
Expanding it  and using  a kind of series reversion, we have, as an *estimate*, the pattern
$$x\sim\frac 1{1+a^5}-\frac {4a^4b}{(1+a^5)^{h+2}}+\frac {2a^3b^2\big[(8h+5)a^5-3\big]}{(1+a^5)^{2h+3}}-$$
$$\frac{4 a^2b^3\big[(24h^2+22h+5)a^{10}-2(9h+5)a^5+1 \big]}{(1+a^5)^{3h+4}}+\cdots$$